# maxHeight ignored on ImageView even with adjustViewBounds

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-image

I have an imageView and I want it to be as big as it can, with a limit in its height, and keeping its aspect ratio, my problem is that this is getting the whole space it can ignoring the maxHeight I set. This is the code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxHeight="100dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_profile"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Why is the maxHeight ignored event with the adjustViewBounds to true? How can I solve that problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try setting android:maxHeight="100dp" fot the LinearLayout and delet that line from image view.

Comment: try `android:scaleType="centerInside"` to `ImageView`

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I tried but it didn't solve the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Here textView is the other content you need to fit on the screen with your image.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxHeight="100dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="hello"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is not working because I want the image to get smaller if it doesn't have space enough. For this reason, weight is required.

Comment: If it is a larger image it will not go beyond 100dp and if it is a smaller image it will retain its original size. I did not understand your use case.

Comment: My problem is that I don't want that the image retain its original size, I want the image to get smaller than its original size in case that the content is bigger than the device's height. So, by setting a smaller size to the imageview, all content would fill the height of the device.